# Android studio indexing every 5 second

Tags: android, android-studio, indexing

my android studio keeps indexing every 5 seconds. I tried invalidating cache, restarting OS, but none of them worked. Android studio version is 4.2.1.
By the way, I have a lot of issues since updating my android studio.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me every 3/4 days and I know this is a temporary solution. By the way, you can solve it by just Invalidate and Restart.

File --> Invalidate Cache/Restart.

If this does not solve your problem you can remove the cache of your android studio by closing Android Studio and running the below lines in your terminal :

rm -rf .idea